# How can I cross verify my propeller thrust?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, propeller, thrust, cfd

I'm simulating a propeller in Ansys and im getting a thrust of 2000N. The forward speed is 85m/s and 240.25 rad/s angular velocity and the diameter of the propeller is 1.8m. Since I'm not able to find any reference values yet I can't tell if my model is accurate. Does this sound like a reasonable value?

Comment: Does it seem reasonable to _you_? (If not, why not?) What makes you think it might _not_ be reasonable?

Comment: 500 lbs thrust at 170 knots @ 2300 rpm 1.8 meter prop is probably "in the ball park", especially if the prop pitch can be adjusted.  But please try to show at least some effort to find references.  We can help more with a specific question about calculations.